# How to add image to the top one user in the list (leaderboard tabel) with create-react-app?

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I made a leaderboard tabel. I want to add a golden star to the top 1 user. The rest should not get anything. But if there is more than 1 user with same points, then the top players should get a star.

```js
render() {
    const { data } = this.props;

    return (
      <ListGroup>
        {data.map((user, index) => (
          <ListGroupItem key={index}>
            <b>
              {user.name} <span style={{ float: "right" }}>{user.total_points}</span>
            </b>
          </ListGroupItem>
        ))}
      </ListGroup>
);
```

This is sorted in the backend, now i want to try to add a small picture to the player on top, the rest should not get anything. Lets say:

User 1 - 20 points
User 2 - 20 points
User 3 - 19 points

Than both User 1 and User 2 get a star.
How can i do that?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: `add a golden star to the top 1 user`, only for 1 player? would there be more than 1 player with the same points? Please update your questions if this is the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it is sorted, the top player is the one with index 0.

So

```js
render() {
    const { data } = this.props; 

    return (
      <ListGroup>
        {data.map((user, index) => (
          <ListGroupItem key={index}>
            {index === 0 && <Image src={user.profile_image} rounded />}
            <b>
              {user.name} <span style={{ float: "right" }}>{user.total_points}</span>
            </b>
          </ListGroupItem>
        ))}
      </ListGroup>
);
```

---

If there might be many top players (top score) then check against that to decide whether to show the image

```js
render() {
    const { data } = this.props;
    // since it is sorted, first user contains the max score as well
    // so we extract it for later comparisons 
    const maxScore = data.length ? data[0].total_points : 0;

    return (
      <ListGroup>
        {data.map((user, index) => (
          <ListGroupItem key={index}>
            {user.total_points===maxScore && <Image src={user.profile_image} rounded />}
            <b>
              {user.name} <span style={{ float: "right" }}>{user.total_points}</span>
            </b>
          </ListGroupItem>
        ))}
      </ListGroup>
);
```

Comment: But what is more players have the same points? Lets say 3 user have 20 points, all the three user should have a star, how would that work?

Comment: @mac123 added alternative that checks agains max score instead of index.

Comment: By some strange reason i get this message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'total_points' of undefined

Comment: @mac123 Most likely an async issue where on initial render the `data` is empty. Try `const maxScore = data.length ? data[0].total_points : 0;`

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional rendering (https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html)

```
render() {
    const { data } = this.props;

    return (
      <ListGroup>
        {data.map((user, index) => (
          <ListGroupItem key={index}>
            {index === 0 && <img src="star.png" alt="" />}
            <b>
              {user.name} <span style={{ float: "right" }}>{user.total_points}</span>
            </b>
          </ListGroupItem>
        ))}
      </ListGroup>
);
```

This is enough to display the image, then it is up to you to style it according to your needs

To account for ties you can do like

```
render() {
    const { data } = this.props;

    return (
      <ListGroup>
        {data.map((user, index, fullArray) => (
          <ListGroupItem key={index}>
            {user.score === fullArray[0].score && <img src="star.png" alt="" />}
            <b>
              {user.name} <span style={{ float: "right" }}>{user.total_points}</span>
            </b>
          </ListGroupItem>
        ))}
      </ListGroup>
);
```

Comment: But what is more players have the same points? Lets say 3 user have 20 points, all the three user should have a star, how would that work?

Comment: @mac123 then impose a condition on the score, I edited the answer with an example